# R operating on lists within lists

Tags: r

In R, I can add 1 to each element of a list by doing `alist<-alist +1`. But what if I have something like `alist<-list(list(1,2,3),list(2,3,4))`. Is there some way to add 1 to each element of the sublist without using a loop?

Comment: Note that `alist` is also a function in base, so avoid naming things that if possible...

Comment: And you cannot add 1 to a list, you must mean atomic vector. Calling it "alist" is just confusing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the question list was written but the example showed a vector. I think the OP meant this:

```
alist <- list(list(1, 2, 3), list(2, 3, 4))
```

Instead of a loop you could use the recursive version of `lapply`, see: `?rapply`.

```
> rapply(alist, function(x) x+1, how = "list" )
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 2

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 3

[[1]][[3]]
[1] 4


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 3

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 4

[[2]][[3]]
[1] 5
```

Answer (score 5):

I just learned about this yesterday; it may be useful to others in similar situations; `[[` allows for recursive indexing into lists, like this.

```
> alist[[c(1,2)]]
[1] 2
```

Comment: How did you engineer that? [[ is for single index selection only, that code should choke with "subscript out of bounds".

Comment: That's what I thought too, but: `‘[[’ can be applied recursively to lists, so that if the single index ‘i’ is a vector of length ‘p’, ‘alist[[i]]’ is equivalent to ‘alist[[i1]]...[[ip]]’ providing all but the final indexing results in a list.`

Comment: Yikes, ok. Got it now, that is awesome!  It's like the matrix indexing for arrays . . .