# Operating on the lists in a list, storing the result in the global environment

Tags: r, list, for-loop, apply, r-mice

I am using mice `library(mice)` to impute a large amount of databases.
I have written a code which makes imputations for all dataframes in my global environment.
The result of this exercise is a large list of lists called `dfmice`.

For each list within the list, I would like to use the `complete` operation of mice
Manually I could do this by doing the following:

```
list1 <- list(a = 2, b = 3)
list2 <- list(c = "a", d = "b")
dfmice <- list(list1, list2)

library(mice)
listitem1 <- dfmice[[1]]
listitem1 <- mice::complete(listitem1)
listitem2 <- dfmice[[2]]
listitem2 <- mice::complete(listitem2)
etc.
```

I however need to do this for about 450 dataframes.

How do I write the loop that does this automatically for each item in the list? I was thinking of something like (thanks @A. Suliman !):

```
try (for (i in 1:length(dfmice))  {
  tryCatch({
    listitem[i]=mice::complete(dfmice[[i]])
  }, error=function(e){cat("ERROR :",conditionMessage(e), "\n")})
})
```

This works, but somehow gives a list where, what should be a dataframe, turns out to be just 1 column. Apparently I am feeding the code a column instead of a dataframe somewhere.

I saw this link: [R operating on lists within lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7653101/r-operating-on-lists-within-lists)
and tried the following without succes:

```
dfmiceimp <- rapply(dfmice, mice::complete, how = "list" )

Error in (function (data, action = 1L, include = FALSE, mild = FALSE,  : 
  'data' not of class 'mids'
```

I would be very happy when someone could show me how to write the syntax for this.

Comment: This `listitem[i]=mice::complete(dfmice[[i]])` will work but I'm getting `ERROR : 'data' not of class 'mids' `

Comment: Thank you for your comment @A.Suliman ! I guess that could be because of the nature of `complete`. It worked for me, sort of.. I am getting a long list of errors haha..

Comment: @A.Suliman Thanks just noticed the missing bracket! The function without `get` sort of works..

Comment: Tom you sould intialize an empty list `listitem` before satrt looping like so `listitem<-list()`

Comment: Also see `?mice::complete`

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help, I am getting closer and closer. The code now works, however, the result is a column with data instead of data.frame per list item. So I guess somewhere I am accidentally feeding it a column instead of a dataframe.